# execute a method in all the ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Maybe it is not possible but here is my question:

I need to execute the same method on all the `ViewController`s, precisely on the `viewDidLoad` or on the `viewDidAppear` methods.

Is there any way on the `AppDelegate` or somewhere of doing this apart from calling this function from every single controller?

Comment: declare and define the method in appdelegate and call it after making object of appdelegate or anothere way make one anothere class common and there declare and define method and make call after importing and making object of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple approach to do this. Follow OOPS & make the use of inheritance like this.

- Make a baseViewController & add two methods for example.

  btBaseViewController.h

  ```
  @interface btBaseViewController : UIViewController 

  @end

  -(void)renderPadUI;
  -(void)renderPhoneUI;
  ```
- Provide a no-op definition for these two methods.

  btBaseViewController.m

  ```
  -(void)renderPhoneUI {
      // to be overridden by derrived classes
  }

  -(void)renderPadUI {
    // to me overridden by derrived classes.
  }
  ```

  And in viewDidLoad do something like this

  ```
   if(IS_IPAD) {
     [self renderPadUI];
   }else{
    [self renderPhoneUI];
   }
  ```
- Now Sub class your ViewControllers from this `btBaseViewController` class as

  btHomeViewController.h

  ```
  @interface btHomeViewController : btBaseViewController

  @end
  ```

Now if you do not provide the definition of methods `renderPhoneUI` and `renderPADUI` `btHomeViewController` the base version will be executed.

Thats simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Create a `BaseViewController`

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
```

and create all other `ViewControllers` by subclassing `BaseViewController`

```
@interface AViewController : BaseViewController
```

and do ypu stuff in `viewDidLoad` or on the `viewDidAppear` of `BaseViewController`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing making a UIViewController subclass that does what you do and make every controller of your app of that new subclass type.

MyUIViewController.h

```
@interface MYUIViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

MYUIViewController.m

```
@implementation MYUIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self myMethodCall];
}
```

And then, every UIViewController that needs to execute this method, should be of MYUIViewController type.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the method in the app delegate or you can make a subclass of a UIViewController